With new installation of Debian, connection to localhost is refused
With a new installation of Debian Bookworm, found that while I could receive mail, no mail went out. I found that connections to localhost are being refused.
$ telnet localhost 25
message goes out but not received

$ telnet localhost 127.0.0.1
Invalid port name '127.0.0.1'

$ wget 127.0.0.1
--2024-12-19 07:14:20--  http://127.0.0.1/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80... failed: Connection refused.

I browse to http://localhost:631/ and connection is refused.

However,
  $ ip a
  1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group def>
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  $ nano /etc/hosts
  127.0.0.1       localhost
  127.0.1.1       iskra.histomat.net      iskra

  # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts 
  ::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
  ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
  ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

